# Rails mysql2 installation on windows

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello everyone I am new to rails I am following lynda tutorial and I am trying to install mysql2 but the error is showing I have look on various page of stack overflow but was not able to resolve it.My Error is

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'mysql2' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: It is listed _https://rubygems.org/gems/mysql2_ ... maybe you have not tried to call: gem install mysql2, but included the quotation marks like 'mysql2'. Try without

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you need to [**use the following**](https://medium.com/@frontlineutils/installing-the-mysql2-rubyonrails-gem-on-windows-7-8-a028f44d87f3#.e6i7z8vns):

- [Download C-Connector](https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.1.6-win32.zip) & unzip to a non-spaced path on your system
- Install the gem referencing the new path:

`gem install mysql2 --platform=ruby -- --with-mysql-dir="C:/path/to/your/c-connector/install/no/spaces"`

This should install the gem, allowing you to proceed with your other installation.

--

The reason this has to be done on Windows is due to the fact that the `mysql2` gem requires an external set of dependencies (the `c-connector` plugin), which Windows does not have installed by default.

Linux users can use `apt-get`, and Mac users `brew` to get the dependencies; Windows users have to download it themselves.

If you follow the steps above, you should get the `mysql2` gem installed.

Answer (score -2):

I think there is some typos in your gemfile, Check if you have type correct version mentioned in the tutorial. mysql gem should look like below.

```
gem 'mysql2', '~> 0.3.11'
```